# Magento 2 custom XML mixed children

Tags: magento2, xml

I am actually moving a custom dataflow extension from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

In M1 we can add custom configuration / mapping for each flow using XML. The XML structure is free and thought by the developer that he use with `getNode()` function in his code.

In M2 I would like to do the same thing. Have a file `flow.xml` where the developer put his flow mapping and configuration.
I create the correct Reader from this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/82049/33619 which is working fine.

Now my issue is with XSD for my `flow.xml` file to tell that node `<mapping></mapping` and `<options></options>` can contain whatever developer wants.
Here are my actual files :

```
# File flow.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Dnd_Flow:etc/flow.xsd">
    <mapping>
        // Here can be string or other nodes on X levels
    </mapping>
    <options>
        // Here can be string or other nodes on X levels
    </options>
</config>
```

My XSD file looks like this :

```
# File flow.xsd

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="config" type="configType" />

    <xs:complexType name="configType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:????" name="mapping" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element type="xs:????" name="options" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I tried `mixed` values, differents element types but no result.
I am new to XSD so I would like to know what is the solution to tell that there can be everything in my nodes ?

Thank you,
Matthéo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my question, I have the solution for other people found this post:

> The type you want is `xsd:anyType`, which you can get either by name:
>
> ```
> <xs:element type="xs:anyType" name="mapping" minOccurs="0" />
> <xs:element type="xs:anyType" name="options" minOccurs="0" />
> ```
>
> or by omitting the `type` attribute:
>
> ```
> <xs:element name="mapping" minOccurs="0" />
> <xs:element name="options" minOccurs="0" />
> ```

Source by C. M. Sperberg-McQueen : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489488/3531064