# Pdf xml in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, pdf, renderer

When developing a payment fee, I want to add a surcharge fee to Pdf. I found the `pdf.xml` config. However, I don't know how it works. Can anyone help me to explain the config pdf xml.

**vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/pdf.xml**

```
<totals>

        <total name="discount">
            <title translate="true">Discount</title>
            <source_field>discount_amount</source_field>
            <title_source_field>discount_description</title_source_field>
            <font_size>7</font_size>
            <display_zero>false</display_zero>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        </total>
```

**UPDATE:**
Good explain here: [Magento 2: How to Read From Configuration Tree](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82022/magento-2-how-to-read-from-configuration-tree/82049#82049)

Comment: The file `pdf.xml` configuration is used in the `Magento\Shipping\Model\Order\Pdf\Packaging`

Answer (score 1):

If you refer vendor\magento\module-sales\etc\pdf.xml

```
....
<totals>
    <total name="subtotal">
        <title translate="true">Subtotal</title>
        <source_field>subtotal</source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>true</display_zero>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </total>
    <total name="discount">
        <title translate="true">Discount</title>
        <source_field>discount_amount</source_field>
        <title_source_field>discount_description</title_source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>false</display_zero>
        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
    </total>
    <total name="shipping">
        <title translate="true">Shipping &amp; Handling</title>
        <source_field>shipping_amount</source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>false</display_zero>
        <sort_order>400</sort_order>
    </total>
    <total name="adjustment_positive">
        <title translate="true">Adjustment Refund</title>
        <source_field>adjustment_positive</source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>false</display_zero>
        <sort_order>500</sort_order>
    </total>
    <total name="adjustment_negative">
        <title translate="true">Adjustment Fee</title>
        <source_field>adjustment_negative</source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>false</display_zero>
        <sort_order>600</sort_order>
    </total>
    <total name="grand_total">
        <title translate="true">Grand Total</title>
        <source_field>grand_total</source_field>
        <font_size>8</font_size>
        <display_zero>true</display_zero>
        <sort_order>700</sort_order>
    </total>
</totals>
```

In this tags, **<souce_field>**, it gets from the fields of **sales_order** table in the database.

If you see your database **sales_order** table, you should find **discount_amount** field.

Each order has the values of totals' fields including **discount_amount**
because your **discount** module saved the value into the field **discount_amount**.